# Adjust hover window size

Tags: carto

Is there a way to make hover windows larger? The CartoDB editor gives the option to make the windows larger on click, but not the hover windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can do it in the custom HTML by changing the width of the top `div` element. You need to add `style="width: 321px;"` to this `div` element. See the animated gif below.

Like the click box, you're capped at 400 pixels wide. The box adjusts to the width of the texts and wraps if it is longer than the width.

[image: Adjust width in hover window]

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the Change HTML button in your Hover tab. In your Custom HTML panel, add style tags above the existing HTML. Between the style tags, add CSS for div.cartodb-tooltip (if you open dev tools you’ll see this is the containing div for your Hover infowindow). You can write your width and max-width values there.